# Delete multiple directories using single delete task

Tags: java, ant

I want to delete two directories `compile.dir` and `jar.dir` using build tool-ant.. So I have to write a targetin  build.xml file below where I have to delete one directory at a time.

```
<target name="clean" description="Delete all generated files">
         <delete dir="${compile.dir}"/>
         <delete dir="${jar.dir}"/>
 </target>
```

Is there any way to delete multiple folders using single delete command like below:

```
 <delete dir="${compile.dir}, ${jar.dir}"/>
```

Comment: Down-voted because the "question does not show any research effort" *(quoted tooltip of down-vote button)*. In this case, "research" means **reading the documentation**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of the [`<delete>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) tasks has examples that show you how:

> Delete all files and subdirectories of build, including build itself.
>
> ```xml
> <delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
>   <fileset dir="build"/>
> </delete>
> ```

The first sentence of the documentation says:

> Deletes a single file, a specified directory and all its files and subdirectories, or a set of files specified by **one or more** [resource collection](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#collection)s.

Which means that you can specify more than one `<fileset>`.

```xml
<delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
  <fileset dir="foo"/>
  <fileset dir="bar"/>
</delete>
```

Comment: I tried using as                                                                                                             
    ```<target name="clean" description="Delete all generated files">    

      <delete>
  <fileset dir="${compile.dir}"/>
  <fileset dir="${jar.dir}" />
      </delete>

     </target>``` But i am not getting any output for it

Comment: @user2755407 You forgot `includeEmptyDirs="true"`.

Comment: added `includeEmptyDirs="true"`.. still  no output..But when i run using the ```<target name="clean" description="Delete all generated files">
         <delete dir="${compile.dir}"/>
         <delete dir="${jar.dir}"/>
 </target>```.. I am getting the output.

Comment: @user2755407 But did the directories get deleted? Yes, they did! If you want to see a list of everything that is deleted, add `verbose="true"`.

Comment: wow! thanks it did..but why is it not showing the same output as when I separately delete  two directories?